# ViewStub inside custom view returning 'ViewStub must have a valid layoutResource'

Tags: android, android-layout

I have implemented a custom view like this:

```
public class HeaderView extends LinearLayout {

    @Bind(R.id.bill_summary_layout)
    LinearLayout summaryLayout;
    @Bind(R.id.bill_balance)
    TextView balance;
    @Bind(R.id.bill_closedate)
    TextView closedDate;
    @Bind(R.id.bill_status)
    TextView status;
    @Bind(R.id.bill_partial_overdue)
    ViewStub partialOverdueView;
    @Bind(R.id.bill_partial_closed)
    ViewStub partialClosedView;
    @Bind(R.id.bill_partial_open)
    ViewStub partialOpenView;

    Bill bill;

    public HeaderView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        initUI(context);
    }

    public HeaderView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        initUI(context);
    }

    public HeaderView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        initUI(context);
    }

    private void initUI(Context context) {
        LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.header_view, this);
    }

    public Bill getBill() {
        return bill;
    }

    public void setBill(Bill bill) {
        this.bill = bill;
        notifyMustRebind();
    }

    public void notifyMustRebind() {
        setupUI();
    }

    private void setupUI() {
        if(this.bill == null)
            throw new RuntimeException("O objeto bill tem que estar setado e nao ser nulo. Talvez esqueceu de chamar o setBill?");

        switch (bill.getState()) {
            case OVERDUE:
                setOverdueState();
                break;
            case OPEN:
                setOpenState();
                break;
            case CLOSED:
                setClosedState();
                break;
            case FUTURE:
                setFutureState();
                break;
        }
    }

    private void setOverdueState(){
        summaryLayout.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(),R.color.overdue));
        LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.partial_overdue_view, this, true);
        partialOverdueView.inflate();
    }

    private void setOpenState(){
        summaryLayout.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(),R.color.open));
        partialOpenView.inflate();
    }

    private void setClosedState(){
        summaryLayout.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(),R.color.closed));
        partialClosedView.inflate();
    }

    private void setFutureState(){
        summaryLayout.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(),R.color.future));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onFinishInflate() {
        super.onFinishInflate();
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDetachedFromWindow() {
        super.onDetachedFromWindow();
        ButterKnife.unbind(this);
    }
}
```

The header_view.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bill_summary_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_content_arrow"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/header_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/header_margin"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bill_balance"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/header_text_margin"
            android:text="R$ 2.300,10"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bill_closedate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/header_text_margin"
            android:text="Vencimento 15 MAI"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bill_status"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/header_text_margin"
            android:text="Fechamento em 5 de Julho"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ViewStub
        android:id="@+id/bill_partial_overdue"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout="@layout/partial_overdue_view"
        />

    <ViewStub
        android:id="@+id/bill_partial_closed"
        layout="@layout/partial_closed_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ViewStub
        android:id="@+id/bill_partial_open"
        layout="@layout/partial_open_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

The view above is inside another view called bill_view:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <br.com.leonardo2204.nubanktest.ui.custom.HeaderView
        android:id="@+id/header_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/list_header_padding">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/list_header_padding"
            android:paddingStart="@dimen/list_header_padding"
            android:text="De 5 Mar até 5 abr"
            android:textAllCaps="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:paddingEnd="@dimen/list_header_padding"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/list_header_padding"
            android:text="Valores em R$"
            android:textAllCaps="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The view above is inflated inside a PagerAdapter, as this:

```
@Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(container.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.bill_view, container, false);
        HeaderView header = (HeaderView) v.findViewById(R.id.header_view);
        header.setBill(billList.get(position));
        container.addView(v);
        return v;
    }
```

The problem is, I'm getting the stack trace below :

```
   Process: br.com.leonardo2204.nubanktest, PID: 10815
                                                                            java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ViewStub must have a valid layoutResource
                                                                                at android.view.ViewStub.inflate(ViewStub.java:289)
                                                                                at br.com.leonardo2204.nubanktest.ui.custom.HeaderView.setClosedState(HeaderView.java:112)
                                                                                at br.com.leonardo2204.nubanktest.ui.custom.HeaderView.setupUI(HeaderView.java:91)
                                                                                at br.com.leonardo2204.nubanktest.ui.custom.HeaderView.notifyMustRebind(HeaderView.java:76)
                                                                                at br.com.leonardo2204.nubanktest.ui.custom.HeaderView.setBill(HeaderView.java:72)
                                                                                at br.com.leonardo2204.nubanktest.ui.adapter.ViewPagerAdapter.instantiateItem(ViewPagerAdapter.java:30)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.addNewItem(ViewPager.java:870)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1086)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:952)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1474)
                                                                                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
```

What I am doing wrong ? Is there a better approach to inflate the header view other than inside `instantiateView` ?

Thanks !

Comment: you forget to post header_view.xml

Comment: Sorry, I'm editing. Thanks !

Comment: I think the problem is `layout` instead `android:layout` in your `ViewStub`(`bill_partial_closed` and `partial_open_view`)

Comment: Wow, what a stupid mistake, that worked ! Please, add this comment as an answer so I can tick it ! And thank you very much !

Comment: Ohh, another thing, setting the `LinearLayout` background color is not working, and backgroundTint is 21+, how can I change the bg color ?

Answer (score 3):

USE

```
android:layout="@layout/xyz"
```

instead of

```
layout="@layout/xyz"
```